# Increment C# int inside <script> tag

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a .cshtml view where I click a `.CompChoice` element, it disapears and another one shows from a specific list.

However, it works for the first time i click the function when the `count` is at 0 and it counts up to 1, changing to the next value in the list. The second time i click the function the value of count is still 0, counting up one and displaying the same value. I want to keep the indexing in C# and the `@{count++;}` appears to works inside the script.

Why is the `@{count++;}` not persistent outside of the `script` tag?

```
@ {
int count = 0;
}

<script>
            $(".CompChoice").on('click', function () {
                $('#@shuffledList[count]').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    @{ count++;}
            $('#@shuffledList[count]').show();
              });
        });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: This will not work. The page is done rendering when the javascript is being executed.

Comment: The prima facie answer to "How do I increment a C# int inside a `<script>` tag" is "You can't."  C# is server-side code (unless you're using Blazor, which I don't think you are).

Comment: Thanks, for making this clear to me. Is there a simple Blazor solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @VDWWD stated, the page is done rendering by the time you click the element.  You see the count increase because as the page is being rendered it executes the `count++` statement (it does not matter if you click anything on the page).  Keep a javascript variable for the count and it will work as expected, however you will still need to pass this value back to your backend in order to do anything with it on the c# side.

Answer (score 1):

You should do that in plain javascript, starting from the server side value.

```
<script>
            var count = @{ count++;};
            $(".CompChoice").on('click', function () {
                $('#@shuffledList[count]').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    count++;
            $('#@shuffledList[count]').show();
              });
        });
</script>
```

When the rendering ends, the user will get on the browser side

```
<script>
            var count = 1;
            $(".CompChoice").on('click', function () {
                $('#@shuffledList[count]').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    count++;
            $('#@shuffledList[count]').show();
              });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and example. I get a new Issue when I change the count to JS. How do i reference a JS var inside a @shuffledList[countJS]. The @ does not recognize the JS variable.